# All files download only through index.php and deny direct access to them from browser

Tags: php

I have the following structure in my website :

- index.php
- files(directory) ---> file1.pdf

How can I prevent the direct access to the file (e.g https://example.com/files/file1.pdf) and allow the file to be downloaded from within the displayed web page for login users?

here is the php code for the index which reads the files from the directory:

```
<?php
        include('session.php');

        $path    = './files';
        $files = scandir($path);
        $files = preg_grep("/^(\.|\.\.|index\.php|\.htaccess)$|.php$|\.meta\.js$/",scandir($path), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
        foreach($files as $file){
          echo '<div>';
          echo "<a href='$file' >$file</a>";
          echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an .htaccess in files and set deny all.

   order deny,allow
   deny from all
2. Create downloader.php and update your download link urls like

domain.com/downloader.php?file=filename

Code :

```
    <?php 

if(!isset($_GET['file']))
{
    die('File Request Not found.');
}
if(!file_exists('files/'.$_GET['file']))
{
    die('File not exists. File name ='.$_GET['file']);
}
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_GET['file']."\""); 
echo readfile('files/'.$_GET['file']);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , i tried the downloader.php ,but it download a file called downloader.php with the value -1 inside .  note that the path is correct

Comment: Please share URL which you generate

Comment: I have added request file and file exist check Please try now.

Comment: Hi @fawad , i managed to make it work , but here the problem, i have a .txt file that contain the word "hello" and when i download the file using the downloader  it return the value "    hello5" and no idea why ?!

Comment: no maybe mistakenly added into your php file or check if you added any echo statement in it.

Comment: @ColinJack Remove the `echo` since `readfile()` is already "output" the content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png)$">

order deny,allow

Deny from all

</FilesMatch>
```

Usage = These rules will allow you to download the files only from index.html and will deny the direct access to them from the browser.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Does this code go into the php file?

Comment: it is index.php not an html file (sorry for that just edited the topic), so as explained above the files should be accessed only from within the index.php which list them along with their links  , i'm new to this an i have two questions , first is this code for FilesMatch (by the way doesn't it need enclosing tag ? ) shoud go inside .htaccess of the folder ? and what do you mean by AddHandler  ? can you please add reference to this ?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how i manged to solve the problem :

in the  .htaccess added the rules :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf|jpe?g|png)$">

order deny,allow

Deny from all

</FilesMatch>
```

So now no one can access the files via direct link from browser .

then added the following code to the downloader.php (of course still needs to be linked to the session to allow logged in users only):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['path']))
{
//Read the filename
$filename = $_GET['path'];
//Check the file exists or not
if(file_exists($filename)) {

//Define header information
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Pragma: public');

//Clear system output buffer
flush();

//Read the size of the file
readfile($filename);

//Terminate from the script
die();
}
else{
echo "File does not exist.";
}
}
else
echo "Filename is not defined."
?>
```

and made a little change to the index.php:

```
 echo "<a href=./downloader.php?path='$pathOF/$file' class='pdfl'>$file</a>";
```

and all working fine , just a little bit delay when requesting a file download , maybe it is a hosting issue or may be the downloader not sure , please let me know if there is a better way to do this .

Regards